# Strange behavior with boost file_sink when forking

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, process, fork

I'm observing some strange behavior when I use a `file_sink` (in boost::iostreams) and then `fork()` a child process.

The child continues the same codebase, i.e., no `exec()` call, because this is done as part of daemonizing the process. My full code fully daemonizaes the process, of course, but I have omitted those steps that are unncessary for reporducing the behavior.

The following code is a *simplified* example that demonstrates the behavior:

```
using namespace std;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

void daemonize(std::ostream& log);


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> logbuf;
  std::ostream filelog(&logbuf);
  //std::ofstream filelog;

  // Step 1: open log
  if (argc > 1)
  {
    //filelog.open(argv[1]);
    logbuf.open(io::file_sink(argv[1]));
    daemonize(filelog);
  }
  else
    daemonize(std::cerr);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void daemonize(std::ostream& log)
{
  log << "Log opened." << endl;

  // Step 2: fork - parent stops, child continues
  log.flush();
  pid_t pid = fork(); // error checking omitted

  if (pid > 0)
  {
    log << "Parent exiting." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  assert(0 == pid); // child continues

  // Step 3: write to log
  sleep(1); // give parent process time to exit
  log << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

If I run this with no argument (e.g., `./a.out`), so that it logs to `stderr`, then I get the expected output:

```
Log opened.
Parent exiting.
Hello World!
```

However, if I do something like `./a.out temp; sleep 2; cat temp` then I get:

```
Log opened.
Hello World!
```

So the parent is somehow no longer writing to the file after the fork. That's puzzle #1.

Now supposed I just move `io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> logbuf;` outside of main so that it's a global variable. Doing that and simply running `./a.out` gives the same expected output as in the previous case, but writing to a file (e.g., temp) now gives a new puzzling behavior:

```
Log opened.
Parent exiting.
Log opened.
Hello World!
```

The line that writes "Log opened." is before the `fork()` so I don't see why that should appear twice in the output. (I even put an explicit `flush()` immediate before the `fork()` to make sure that line of output wasn't simply buffered, and then the buffer got copied during the `fork()` and later both copies eventually flushed to the stream...) So that's puzzle #2.

Of course, if I comment out the whole `fork()` process (the entire section labeled as "Step 2") then it behaves as expected for both file and `stderr` output, and regardless of whether `logbuf` is global or local to `main()`.

Also, if I switch `filelog` to be an `ofstream` instead of `stream_buffer<file_sink>` (see commented out lines in `main()`) then it also behaves as expected for both file and `stderr` output, and regardless of whether `filelog`/`logbuf` are global or local to `main()`.

So it really seems that it's an interaction between `file_sink` and `fork()` producing these strange behaviors...  If anyone has ideas on what may be causing these, I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it figured out... creating this answer for posterity / anyone who stumbles on this questions looking for an answer.

I observed this behavior in boost 1.40, but when I tried it using boost 1.46 everything behaved in the expected manner in *all* cases, i.e.:

```
Log opened.
Parent exiting.
Hello World!
```

So my assumption right now is that this was actually a bug in boost that was fixed sometime between version 1.41-1.46. I didn't see anything in the release notes that made it real obvious to me that they found & fixed the bug, but it's possible the release notes discussed fixing some underlying cause of this bug and I wasn't able to make the conneciton between that underlying cause and this scenario.

In any case, the solution seems to be to install boost version >= 1.46